# Bind dynamically created D3 elements with an event through another function call

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a beginner in jquery and a total newbie to d3 and have a question: How to bind dynamically created d3 elements through another function call?

This is how it works for me so far:

```
    $.fn.drawDummy = function(){
        var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");       

        var rect = g.append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "rectPassive")
                    .attr("rx","20")
                    .attr("ry","20")
                    .attr("width","200")
                    .attr("height","50");

        // direct d3 event binding in jquery function
        g.on("mouseover", function(){
            d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("class","rectActive");  
        });
     }
```

Instead, I would like to encapsulate the event function outside the function where I create the d3 elements (my imaginary thoughts):

```
    $.fn.drawDummy = function(){
        var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");       

        var rect = g.append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "rectPassive")
                    .attr("rx","20")
                    .attr("ry","20")
                    .attr("width","200")
                    .attr("height","50");

        // binding through a function call
        g.bindGOnMouseoverHandler();
     };

     bindGOnMouseoverHandler = function(){
        d3.select(this).on("mouseover", function(){
            d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("class","rectActive");  
        });  
     };
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly clear **why** you want to do that. Anyway, the selection obviously doesn't have a method named `bindGOnMouseoverHandler`. That said, what you want can be done with `selection.call`, which:

> Invokes the specified function exactly once, passing in this selection along with any optional arguments. Returns this selection. This is equivalent to invoking the function by hand but facilitates method chaining. [(source)](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call)

Thus, it would be:

```
g.call(bindGOnMouseoverHandler);
```

And then (mind the `const` here, you don't want globals):

```
const bindGOnMouseoverHandler = function(selection){
    selection.on("mouseover", function(){
        d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("class","rectActive");  
    });  
 };
```

Comment: The reason is that I create multiple but slightly different D3 elements in multiple loops reading out an XML file. Such an event handler becomes very useful because some elements have similar but not the exact same number of events as others. 
Thank you - it works! Once I have enough reputation, I will give you an upvote :-)